# Save oCompany in a cookie or session

Tags: php, sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

Does anyone know how I can save the variable oCompany from Sap b1 DiAPI in a cookie or in a session to reuse it?

```
$oCompany = new COM("SAPbobsCOM.Company")or die ("No connection");
```

Comment: Or also how could I save the connection result

Comment: I can't answer for PHP, but my advice for someone using this with ASP.Net would be 'don't'. You probably don't want a lumbering great COM object hanging around in your session state, and the DIAPI can be unstable so could take out your web application. I'd put it in a back-end service with a queue between them.

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536889/save-ocompany-object-to-reusable-variable-sap-b1-di-api/69144063#69144063, which is also your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save oCompany object to reusable variable, Sap b1 Di Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66536889/save-ocompany-object-to-reusable-variable-sap-b1-di-api)